# How to do Query & show the result in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to dislpay all the data from table: room that has id = 1

but no result came out
here is my code:

```
public function show($id)
{
        $room_list         = Room::where('house_id','=','1');

        return view('book.show', compact('room_list'));
}
```

in view

```
    <?php foreach($room_list as $room): ?>
     Room Number: {{room->house_id}}
     <?php endforeach ?>
```

but no result appear, even the Room Number label is not appear meaning the query result is empty.
I already check the table room, it has data wih house_id = 1

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try this: Room::where('house_id', 1)->get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function show($id)
{
        $room_list = Room::where('house_id','=',$id)->get();

        return view('book.show', compact('room_list'));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($room_list as $room)
     Room Number: {{$room->house_id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Work perfectly! 
Yes, actually i'm going to use $id to get the result. and now i'm using exactly as your answer.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function show($id)
{
   $room_list = Room::where('house_id','=','1')->get();
   // get() will return all the matching records that fulfill the condition criteria 

   return view('book.show', compact('room_list'));
   // here compact('room_list') will pass the variable named $room_list to the view
}
```

**View:** You can use `$room_list` variable on view like:

```
@foreach($room_list as $room)
    Room Number: {{$room->house_id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Work perfectly! I think i should follow the standard format from the document instead of using the example on my guidance book. 

Very clear explanation also.
Thank you! :)